# DynamoDB Stream to EventBridge

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-event-bridge

I need to get data from DynamoDB into EventBrdige.  Can this happen without the need of a Lambda Function? Can EventBridge listen to DynamoDB changes as a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is currently no direct integration between DynamoDB Stream and EventBridge.

You need to consider the different use cases for these two services. [Event Bridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) is for highly important low-volume events for simpler systems integration, while DynamoDB is for high-volume events, which are already recorded in the DB. DynamoDB Stream is designed chiefly for analytical use cases with the ability to aggregate or filter the events to analyze.

There are a few other event processing services in AWS, such as [Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) and [Managed Kafka](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/), which are designed differently for scale than Event-Bridge.

Comment: Thank you Guy for the reply.  For now our chief wants us to follow this pattern so I'll work on the Lambda function that will move the events.  Will propose Kinesis but I think he has his mind set on EventBridge.

Comment: In addition to this, 2 weeks ago AWS released EventBridge Pipe that can have DynamoDB stream as a source https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-dynamodb.html